# Turn R list of dates into vector

Tags: r

I have a list of Dates which is returned by a function and looks like the following:

```
$`2014-03-02T05:20:13,2014-03-02T05:20:13`
[1] "2014-03-02" "2014-03-02"

$`2013-12-04T21:06:28,2013-12-04T21:06:37,2013-12-04T21:06:46,2013-12-04T21:06:49,2013-12-04T21:07:16,2014-01-09T16:20:55,2014-01-09T18:20:59,2014-01-09T18:21:08,2014-01-09T18:21:08`
[1] "2013-12-04" "2013-12-04" "2013-12-04"
[4] "2013-12-04" "2013-12-04" "2014-01-09"
[7] "2014-01-09" "2014-01-09" "2014-01-09"
```

I would like to put all the individual elements of the list into a vector of Dates. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To preserve the Date class, if your list is called `d` you can use `do.call(c, d)`.

Comment: `Error in do.call(c, d) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function`


This worked better for me:

`do.call("c", d)`

Comment: @AndresKull Hmm have you overwritten `c` by assigning some value to it? If you have stored a number in it like `c <- 15` and then you run `do.call(c, d)` it will find the number `c` before it finds the function `c` in the search path.

Comment: Excellent answer @konvas really helpful, just what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Just another option

If your list of dates is called dateList, use the following:

```
Reduce(c, dateList)
```